# Do I gain anything by using "proper" replicas for a read-only MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, high-availability

I have a web-app that depends on a read-only MongoDB database. Through trial and error, I discovered that by far the fastest way to run the ETL pipeline that populates the database is to run a local copy of MongoDB, populate the database, stop the database, and tarball the state directory.

To deploy a high-availability "cluster," I create multiple instances (or containers) running the app, each with access to a copy of the state in locally mounted storage. Putting these behind a load balancer with regular health checks and autoscaling (or in a Kubernetes cluster as a `ReplicaSet`), I get isolation, redundancy, easy rollbacks (using versioned storage), and easy setup in virtually any environment.

The key idea here is that because the database is read-only, it is in a sense a "stateless" application. Thus, I can treat it like any other static provider of information

There are many apparent advantages to this setup. Nevertheless, I have always had a nagging feeling that I was missing something. Given a read-only context, is there still some reason why it might be better to run a "proper" MongoDB cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind outages when the single node goes down and you don't mind taking the system down during upgrades then this is probably an ok deployment. You might get a safer dump and restore using `mongodump` and `mongorestore` rather than `tar` but apart from that this setup should work for a read-only deployment.

Comment: Not a single node deployment--as I said, autoscaling is very easy. On AWS, you set up a user script that downloads and uncompresses the snapshot before starting the database. You can use spot instances in the autoscaling group and put the whole thing behind a load balancer. You never get an outage.